# How can I add the selected photos from my intent to my adapter, by the order they were chosen?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using this intent to pick multiple images:

```
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select photos"), 17)
```

And then won activity result, I get the data and load them all into my recycler's adapter.
But I've noticed that the order in which they are loaded into the adaper has nothing to do with the order in which they were chosen.
Can I make the `clipData` be ordered by the order in which the photos were chosen?

Comment: I don't think you can get the original order